# JS error when I set an object property to Nested property, a function, or an array

Tags: javascript

Very new to JS using VSCode trying out examples in tutorials. Ran into this error when I and setting an object's properties. The first properties such as `firstname`, `lastname`, and `age` seem to log fine, however when I try to use an array, a function or nested properties, as a property of the object I get an error and it will not log to console.

The error is:

> " "." expected. (TS1005)

Please advise, total noob but trying hard to learn more so please forgive my ignorance at this point.

```js
   var person = {
       firstname: 'Matilda',
       lastname:'Milner',
       age: 68
       kids: ['Dave', 'Lynn', 'Cal', 'August', 'Cade'],
       location: {
                street: '500 Some St.',
                city: 'Inola',
                state: 'Oklahoma',
                zip: '66702',
                }
        
        fullname: function(){
           return this.firstname + " " + lastname;
        }      
   }
   console.log(person.firstname +" "+person.lastname + " " +"is"+ " " + person.age+ " "+ "years old");
   console.log(person.kids[3])
   console.log(person.address.zip)
```

Comment: thank you! I now see that I missed the comma after the numerical value of 68 which made the proceeding lines to error. and in my attempt to see if I had used a reserved word I did not update the following lines to the new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few syntax errors in your code

- You missed `,` at lots of places in your object definition.
- You missed `this` before `lastname` in your `fullname` function
- You don't have any property called `address` but you're trying to access `person.address.zip`

```js
var person = {
       firstname: 'Matilda',
       lastname:'Milner',
       age: 68,
       kids: ['Dave', 'Lynn', 'Cal', 'August', 'Cade'],
       location: {
                street: '500 Some St.',
                city: 'Inola',
                state: 'Oklahoma',
                zip: '66702',
                },
        
        fullname: function(){
           return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
        }      
   }
   console.log(person.firstname +" "+person.lastname + " " +"is"+ " " + person.age+ " "+ "years old");
   console.log(person.kids[3])
   console.log(person.location.zip)
   console.log(person.fullname())
```